# Wipe data of a emulator in VS Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

VS Code equivalent of this (wipe data of a emulator):

[image]

How to edit an emulator (in VS Code) will also help.

Comment: Make sure emulator has to close before wipe data

Comment: I don't think VS code has that option, you can only create a new emulator and run it, but you can do this in visual studio.